# How do I use python to take a dataset with occupancy counts at precise times and return a dataset with max values per hour?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-cleaning

I would like to take a dataset that offers a count of how many people are present at a location every 15 minutes (e.g. 13 people at Location A at 21:45, 29 people at Location A at 21:30, etc.), and instead have the dataset show the maximum number of people that occupied the location in any hour (e.g. between 21:00 and 21:59, the maximum occupancy at Location A was 33 - it doesn't matter if the maximum count of 33 people happened at 21:00, 21:15, 21:30 or 21:45).

My starting point is a csv that looks like this (it has thousands of entries, but this is just as an example):

```
+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|        TIME        | LOC A | LOC B | LOC C | LOC D | LOC E | LOC F |
+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 8/28/2020 22:00:22 | 5     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 10    | 0     |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 8/28/2020 21:45:21 | 13    | 10    | 23    | 14    | 24    | 0     |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 8/28/2020 21:30:22 | 29    | 13    | 31    | 26    | 35    | 7     |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 8/28/2020 21:15:22 | 32    | 17    | 41    | 32    | 49    | 12    |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 8/28/2020 21:00:22 | 33    | 24    | 50    | 43    | 64    | 15    |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 8/28/2020 20:45:23 | 44    | 31    | 60    | 47    | 88    | 15    |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 8/28/2020 20:30:22 | 48    | 36    | 70    | 48    | 120   | 25    |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 8/28/2020 20:15:23 | 48    | 42    | 82    | 57    | 124   | 26    |
+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

And to confirm, the value in the columns is the number of people present at that location at that precise time.

And my goal is something that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|        TIME        | LOC A | LOC B | LOC C | LOC D | LOC E | LOC F |
+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 2020-08-28 22:00   | 5     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 10    | 0     |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 2020-08-28 21:00   | 33    | 24    | 50    | 43    | 64    | 15    |
|                    |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 2020-08-28 20:00   | 48    | 42    | 82    | 57    | 124   | 26    |
+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

So, for example, if the counts for a location for 14:00, 14:15, 14:30, and 14:45 were 5,7,12,6 respectively, then the new entry for that location would just show 14:00 and the value of 12 (because that was the max count of people in that period).

I hope I've explained that okay. I'm still very new to python, and I'm fully confident that this can be done, I just don't quite know how.

Any help would be massively appreciated - thanks so much in advance ʕ •ᴥ•ʔ

Comment: I cannot connect the numbers in your question. Sorry cannot help.

Comment: I've edited - hope that makes more sense. Basically, my starting dataset shows a count of people present at a location (for Locations A, B, C, D, E and F) at a given snapshot in time (the Time column). What I would like to turn this into, is a dataset that shows the max count for the whole hour. For example, it doesn't matter if the max count (i.e. the highest number of people present at the location at the same time) happened on the hour, at 15 minutes past, at 30 minutes past, or at 45 minutes past. The value returned would be the maximum during that hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby on your index that should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Time':'2020-01-01 21:15:00', 'LOCA':3,'LOCB':0},
                   {'Time':'2020-01-01 21:00:00', 'LOCA':4, 'LOCB':10},
                   {'Time':'2020-01-01 20:00:00', 'LOCA':3,'LOCB':1},
                   {'Time':'2020-01-01 20:03:00', 'LOCA':12, 'LOCB':0},
                   {'Time':'2020-01-05 21:15:00', 'LOCA':3,'LOCB':0}])

#df.set_index(df['Time'],inplace = True)
df.set_index('Time', inplace = True)   #That is the proper way to do it
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
#df.drop(['Time'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

df = df.groupby([df.index.date, df.index.hour]).max()

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try this as soon as I'm home :) As an aside, the timestamp in the original dataset isn't currently a datetime object (I think it is just a text string). Do you know how I would change that?

Comment: Yes, try pd.to_datetime() as in the code snippet above. I also used a string for the date when I created the DataFrame.

Comment: I'll try it and report back. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer :) Massively appreciated!

Comment: Just using pd.to_datetime() didn't work. However, doing this as as a separate line of code works: df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'). So the date is now in the correct datetime format. How do I integrate this with the rest of the code you've kindly provided?

Comment: set the df['Time'] column as your index: df.set_index(df['Time'], inplace = True) next drop the Time column: df.drop(['Time'], axis = 1, inplace = True) and apply the groupby: df = df.groupby([df.index.date, df.index.hour]).max() that should work.

Comment: It works :D Thank you soooooo much! Eternally grateful for you taking the time, and I also learnt a lot there.